# Get data from selected row from DataGrid using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a `datagrid` and I want the data in the selected row to be shown in a `textbox`. I am using `.NET 2003`. All I found is the solution for `datagridview`. I tried this code and also `SelectedRows` but the function does not exist in `datagrid`.

```
Private Sub Grid2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Grid2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i, j As Integer
    i = Grid2.CurrentRow.Index
    TextBox1.Text = Grid2.Item(0, i).Value
    TextBox2.Text = Grid2.Item(1, i).Value
    TextBox3.Text = Grid2.Item(2, i).Value
    TextBox4.Text = Grid2.Item(3, i).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry i copy the wrong code. this is the real code. actually grid2 is a data grid and not datagridview. so i try to change datagridview as grid2 but error

Comment: the error is at 'CurrentRow' is not a member of data grid

Comment: Grid2 is a DataGrid. because i using asp.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Grid2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Grid2.SelectedIndexChanged
    TextBox1.Text = Grid2.SelectedItem.Cells(0).Text
    TextBox2.Text = Grid2.SelectedItem.Cells(1).Text
    TextBox3.Text = Grid2.SelectedItem.Cells(2).Text
    TextBox4.Text = Grid2.SelectedItem.Cells(3).Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. how can i transfer the value in to a different page? because i would like display the data on different page when user click the button

Comment: Kindly mark this as answered if it works by clicking the check button.

Comment: Regarding that, you can use [Session()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).